# Flutter: Location is not getting current location for the second time

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem when using Location package from Flutter. So the case is I want to track user location using Location package and show it using Google Maps. When the application loaded for the first time and I navigate to the map screen (which I use the Location package), it works fine and showing my emulator current location. But when I go to the home screen and go back to the map screen, the current location is null and not getting any value.

Case 1 (works):
Load app first time -> home screen -> map screen -> current location is updated

Case 2 (not works):
Load app first time -> home screen -> map screen -> current location is updated -> home screen -> map screen -> current location is not updated and always null

Here is my code:

```
import "dart:async";

import "package:dayagreen/ui/widgets/app_bar.dart";
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart";
import "package:location/location.dart";

class ChargingStationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChargingStationScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChargingStationScreen> createState() => _ChargingStationScreenState();
}

class _ChargingStationScreenState extends State<ChargingStationScreen> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();

  LocationData? currentLocation;
  BitmapDescriptor? markerIcon = BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker;

  Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();
    bool _serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;

    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    location.getLocation().then((value) {
      currentLocation = value;
      print(currentLocation!.latitude!);
    });

    GoogleMapController googleMapController = await _controller.future;

    location.onLocationChanged.listen((newLocation) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = newLocation;
        print(currentLocation!.latitude!);
        googleMapController.animateCamera(
          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
            CameraPosition(
              zoom: 14.4746,
              target: LatLng(
                  currentLocation!.latitude!, currentLocation!.longitude!),
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
    });
  }

  void addCustomIcon() {
    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(const ImageConfiguration(),
            "assets/images/maps_current_location.png")
        .then(
      (icon) {
        setState(() {
          markerIcon = icon;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // addCustomIcon();
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const MainAppbar(
        title: "Charging Station",
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target:
              LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!, currentLocation!.longitude!),
          zoom: 14.4746,
        ),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        markers: {
          Marker(
            markerId: const MarkerId("current_position"),
            position:
                LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!, currentLocation!.longitude!),
            icon: markerIcon!,
          )
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I try to follow the tutorial on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9hsWOCXb_o but still not working for me. I am expecting that whenever the user navigate to other page and going back to map screen, the location is working.